# Laravel (5.6) how to seed tables with relationships to other tables

Tags: php, laravel

Currently got some downtime and thought I’d play around with laravel as I usually just use it for basic web dev.

I’ve tried seeders and like how it’s quicker for me to drop test data into a table but I’m not sure how I go about doing this for multiple tables which have relationships.

In my case let’s say I’ve got 3 tables, a customer table, a customer address table and a customer purchase table.

Seeding the customer table is easy because it’s the main table but the other two tables have a column called customer_id which is the reference back to the customer table.

If I want to use seeders how do I write the code to make X amount of customers and then make the following records in the other tables which link back the created customers.

Apologies if I’ve missed something in the documentation.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#using-factories scroll down to Relationships

Comment: Thanks I will have a read, I’m more of a build on first look without reading :-)

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to set up the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) on the `Customer` model. I assume the `Customer` model has [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship with `CustomerAddress` and `CustomerPurchase` models.

```
<?php

// app/Customer.php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerAddress::class);
    }

    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerPurchase::class);
    }
}
```

Next, you're going to need to define a [model factory](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#writing-factories).

```
<?php

// database/factories/CustomerFactory.php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\CustomerAddress::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'address' => $faker->streetAddress,
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\CustomerPurchase::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'item' => $faker->word,
        'amount' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 10, 200),
    ];
});
```

Now all you have to do is use those model factories to seed random records on the database. You can still use the Eloquent collection and [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#relationships) just fine:

```
<?php

// database/seed/DatabaseSeeder.php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Customer::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($customer) {
            $customerAddresses = factory(App\CustomerAddress::class, 2)->make();
            $customerPurchases = factory(App\CustomerPurchase::class, 5)->make();

            $customer->addresses()->saveMany($customerAddresses);
            $customer->purchases()->saveMany($customerPurchases);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Best solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

Some modified code from documentation:

```
$users = factory(Customer::class, 3)
       ->create()
       ->each(function ($u) {
            $u->addresses()->save(factory(Address::class)->make());
            $u->purchases()->saveMany(factory(Purchase::class, 10)->make());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple make a `foreach` statement

```
$customers = factory(Customer::class,N)->create();
foreach( $customers as $customer)
{
     factory(CustomerAddress::class)->create([
          'customer_id' => $customer->id
     ]);

     factory(CustomerPurchase::class)->create([
          'customer_id' => $customer->id
     ]);
}
```

**NOTE** This is recommended only in case you want to have an address and purchase for every customer.
Else you should treat the seeding differently and not provide an address and purchase for every customer.
This will make your tests less reliable

Comment: Yeah I thought about making a for each and emulating data with faker but thought there must be a sensible way of doing it

Comment: how to use the variable 'customer_id' inside factory?